# Python argparse save argument into a variable

Tags: python

Im trying to save the argparse argument into a variable.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   
parser.add_argument('-n', dest='noww', action='store', help="shows noww")

args = parser.parse_args()

print(noww)
```

but its giving this error.

```
 python c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/testing.py  -n sdad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/testing.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(noww)
NameError: name 'noww' is not defined
```

Comment: Where did you define `noww`? It is not in the code posted. Did you mean `print(args)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be args.noww instead of noww.

Answer (score 2):

When you make the `parse_args` call, you get back a `Namespace` object:

```
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['-n', 'sdad'])
>>> args
Namespace(noww='sdad')
```

From here you can access the value as an attribute:

```
>>> args.noww
'sdad'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat your argument a bit.

`parser.add_argument('-n', '--now', action='store_true', help="shows noww")`
`args = parser.parse_args()`

`print(args.now)`

When using optional arguments, use -- to define the variable name you will use throughout and then you can call it like such.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `args` to a dictionary using `vars`

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   
parser.add_argument('-n', dest='noww', action='store', help="shows noww")

args = parser.parse_args()
args = vars(args)

print(args["noww"])
```

Comment: If you leave out the `args = vars(args)` then you can simply use `args.noww` to access the `-n` flag value. There is no need to convert it to a dictionary.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Even I thought the same, and ran the script using`print(args.noww)` but I got error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'noww'`

Comment: But did you remove the `vars` call _and_ use `args.noww` instead of `args["noww"]`? It sounds like you are still trying to access `args` as a dictionary. Here, [try it on Repl.it](https://repl.it/@geary/StackOverflow-63224465). If you click the Run button you will see it print `None` (for the first `parse_args` call with no arguments) and then `howdy` (for the second `parse_args` call with an argument).